# Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'. error

Tags: connection-string

I have uploaded my website on web server cyberhost.com. They send me some information after purchasing web hosting. In which the Nameserver 1: ns4.clientns.net .And I got the following error

Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

and my connection string is-  `connection String="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|himTravels.mdf;User Id=maantravels_db;Password=V*f357ghtff;User Instance=true"`

What will the solution of it?? Thank you in advance. I don't have enough knowledge about connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing \  `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\himTravels.mdf;`
and also missing `Initial Catalog`

---

```
connection String="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Dbname;Integrated Security=True;
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\himTravels.mdf;User Id=maantravels_db;Password=V*f357ghtff;User Instance=true"
```